# Custom object tab not appearing under Salesforce1 Mobile Navigation settings

Tags: salesforce

I am planing to add one of our custom object tab under APP section in salesforce1 navigation menu. To do this I need to place custom object tab below smart search in Mobile Navigation settings. But my custom object tab is not listed under available section inside Mobile Navigation settings. The tab is already created and added to my available tab in full sales force. Anything missing or something else has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Object tabs won't necessarily show up in the Recently Searched objects in the Navigation Menu on its own accord. Those tabs are rendered on a per-user basis, based on what a user has searched for in full (non-mobile) Salesforce recently.

A user can "pin" objects they search for in full Salesforce. This causes the object to be pinned to the Recently Searched objects list in the Salesforce1 Navigation menu.

Custom elements that can be added to the Navigation Menu in Salesforce1 include:

- AppExchange apps
- Canvas apps
- Visualforce pages
- Flexipages